# Why C#.Net only allows for 5 thread priorities to choose from?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-priority

I'm wondering why does .NET only offer 5 thread priorities (i.e. highest, aboveNormal, etc.) to choose from if Windows OS uses 32 priorities?

Comment: Five priority levels ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: This is one of those "you would have to ask Microsoft" questions.

Comment: I don't agree to all the downvotes and putting it on hold. There's a clear answer to it.

Comment: priority level != priority class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses the process priority together with the thread priority to calculate the overall priority.
Once you know that, you can google for process priorities and perhaps you find [Scheduling Priorities on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would highly appreciate if you could read the book *Windows Internals 6th edition, part 1*, which describes it in detail on page 410++.

In C# you can try

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal;
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

and look at the results with ProcessExplorer.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. So the combination of process priority and thread priority will allow me to use more than the 5 priorities I mentioned above on Windows OS. I would have checked this answer as useful if I was able to, but unfortunately I can't because of all the downvotes I got!